# Use VSCode icons in Windows Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is it possible to somehow export icons from VSCode theme, and use them as the official icons in all places, e.g. Windows Explorer?

Comment: You would somehow need to overwrite the ` C:\windows\system\shell32.dll` icons.

Comment: @ifconfig Only for the folder icon... but what I had in mind was to use the icons for the file formats.

Answer (score 3):

The VS Code team [added this in 1.28 update](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_28#_file-icons-per-file-type). The icon cache of the OS needs to be invalidated after the update. You may have to reinstall VS Code in order to see the updated icons.

There are still some limitations:

- Only macOS and Windows are supported
- Icons are not provided for all file types
- File type icons are visible only for larger icon views (UPDATE: small icons are added in v1.29)

Comment: I've reset my os (win10) icon cache using [this method](https://www.howtogeek.com/232779/how-to-rebuild-a-broken-icon-cache-in-windows-10/) and restarted my system but no result.

Comment: Later I reinstalled Visual Code and during the install process I checked the checkbox that reads  "Register Code as an editor for supported file types". That helped.